# unexpected error messages in just installed fresh WooCommerce theme

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

after enabling WP_DEBUG I can see following errors:

```
Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 0 in /var/www/foo.com/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-geo-ip.php on line 1592

Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 1 in /var/www/foo.com/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-geo-ip.php on line 1592

Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 2 in /var/www/foo.com/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-geo-ip.php on line 1592

Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 3 in /var/www/foo.com/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-geo-ip.php on line 1592

Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 4 in /var/www/foo.com/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-geo-ip.php on line 1592

Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 5 in /var/www/foo.com/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-geo-ip.php on line 1592
```

N.B. - I haven't changed any WooCommerce core file, using default storefront theme, just installed, fresh & untouched.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a notice, nothing to worry about about the code, i suspect that your installation does not have the geoip database, as it is fresh. The woocommerce check status page will show that.
I think that the database could be downloaded here http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/legacy/geolite/
then it should be put in it's specific folder.

Hope this helps.
Reply if you need to discuss it more

Comment: which files to be downloaded and where to put?...
it's ruining the dashboard & everything whenever I enable WP_DEBUG
but I need to enable the wp_debug, so need a solution

Comment: Go to woocommerce status page, they have the help. this may not be the cause, as i have created a fresh storefront installation and didnot get the warning on html even with  define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', true ) in wp-config.php;